# how to do text enter and button click on exe programs with python without moving cursor or taking control of keyboard?

Tags: python, windows

I would like to do text enter and button click in the background on exe programs with having my python code actually moving the cursor and taking control of keyboard.

example would be to click save button on OneNote and type in save directory. the python code would do it all quietly in the background.

Comment: UI Automation...

Comment: pywinauto with the `uia` backend.